# Jquery hasClass + If Statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I want the following loadContent function to load the target div only if the link clicked has a certain class.  This is what I've come up with so far:

```
function loadContent(targetDIV, sourceURL) {
if ( $(this).hasClass("done") ) {
$(""+targetDIV+"").load(""+sourceURL+"");
}
}

<a href="javascript:loadContent('#nav', 'news.php');" class="done">News</a>
```

The function works without the if statement, but I just can't seem to get the hasClass to work with the if - any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to the following, and it should work:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadContent.call(this, '#nav', 'news.php');" class="done">News</a>
```

---

By using `.call()`, you're setting the value of `this` in the `loadContent` function to the current element.

And because we used `onclick`, `this` in the inline handler will give you that reference to pass on.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it does not work because the reference to "this" in your function is not actually referring to the link. Pass the link itself to the function for better results:

```
function loadContent(linkObj, targetDIV, sourceURL) {
    if ( $(linkObj).hasClass("done") ) {
        $(""+targetDIV+"").load(""+sourceURL+"");
    }
}

<a href="javascript:loadContent(this, '#nav', 'news.php');" class="done">News</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using href="javascript:..." could you perhaps use the jquery click() method to bind your click?

I'm not sure if "this" is set correctly as you've got it but I think using jquery click will ensure "this" is what you're expecting. I also think it's more clear.